# AWS Elasticache Redis connection using laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-elasticache, predis

These are the current configurations I am using.

In **.env** file

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST="Primary Endpoint"
REDIS_PASSWORD="Password"
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_SCHEME =tcp
```

In **config/database.php**

[image: screenshot]

And I am getting an error like this `ConnectionException in AbstractConnection.php line 155: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]`

I wanted to know the correct configurations in `.env` file and `config/database.php` file.

**Note:**

- Laravel version 5.3
- predis version 1.1.*@dev

Comment: is elastic cache is allowed to connect remotely?

Comment: Yes it is allowed.

Comment: I think your new config is not loaded. Try run `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and also restart all your queue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my AWS  EC2 (RedHat 8) instance not connecting to my AWS Elastcache despite the security group being well set up.
This solved my problem:

`/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1`

By default, SELinux does not allow Apache to make socket connections. More information can be found [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/apache)

My laravel config/database.php file is as follows:
[image]

My security group that is linked to Redis has the following inbound rules:

[image]

All the best.

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'd rather set the source of the Redis security group to point to the security group of the EC2 just to be extra secure.

Answer (score -7):

First, you should install and start Redis server on your server. If not install start redis server. Following are the commands for install and starting a redis server

1. Open the terminal and hit the following command

   sudo apt-get install redis-server
2. Hit the below command to check whether Redis is installed or not

   redis-server
3. To start Redis server use the following command

   service redis-server start
4. To automatically restart Redis server on system reboot  use the following command

   update-rc.d redis-server enable

   update-rc.d redis-server defaults

Referece
https://medium.com/@petehouston/install-and-config-redis-server-on-ubuntu-linux-16-04-3c59729e12cc

https://tuts.codingo.me/improve-site-loading-speed-using-redis

Comment: Faizan I think elasticache is separate service to use redis and not a redis running on a web server ( e.g. ec2 ) itself.